# Excel VBA Program to Get Info From File Name

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a Excel VBA code and it's purpose is to take information from file names and export it into excel. The code works find except that it skips the first file name. This is my first time coding in VBA so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
Sub Get_Model_File_Names()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xDirect, xFname

    'DIRECTORY TO SELECT FOLDER FROM
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Please select a folder"
        .Show

        'LOCATES FILES
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            xFname = Dir(xDirect)

            'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
            Do While xFname <> ""

                'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
                xFname = Left(Dir, 10)
                DrawingNumb = Left(xFname, 7)
                RevNumb = Mid(xFname, 10, 2)

                'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
                ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = DrawingNumb
                ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = RevNumb
                xRow = xRow + 1
             Loop

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

- Fen

Comment: I've tried changing .selecteditems (1) to (0) and messed around with xRow = xRow +1 but an error message came up.

Answer (score 0):

Move `xFname = Left(Dir, 10)` so that it is after `ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = RevNumb`

Calling `xFname = Left(Dir,10)` is selecting the next file in the directory.

`xFname = Dir(xDirect)` is getting the first file before the loop is entered. That one needs to be processed first.

I have this right now running without any error:

```
Sub Get_Model_File_Names()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect, xFname

'DIRECTORY TO SELECT FOLDER FROM
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .Show

    'LOCATES FILES
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname = Left(Dir(xDirect), 10)

        'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
        Do While xFname <> ""

            'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
            DrawingNumb = Left(xFname, 7)
            RevNumb = Mid(xFname, 10, 2)

            'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = DrawingNumb
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = RevNumb
            xFname = Left(Dir(), 10)
            xRow = xRow + 1
         Loop

    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but now the first RevNumb does not show up. For instance...

9012472 jt
9012472 7
9012473 7

the "jt" should be a number

Comment: Right now you are getting xFname two different ways. I'm not sure what your data looks like, but try this: change `xFname = Dir(xDirect)` to be `xFname = Left(Dir(xDirect), 10)`.

Comment: Dir is returning a string.  You can work with the Left and Mid functions to get what you need from it.  It is also helpful to set a breakpoint and watch it all in the debugger.

Comment: I tried uploading a pic so it's easier see what is going on with the code but I was uable to do so...

Comment: `xFname = Left(Dir(xDirect), 10)` is getting the Left 10 characters of the first filename in the directory.  I used that because it was similar to the `xFname = Left(Dir,10)` that you had in the loop that selected the next filenames.  Maybe Left 10 is not what you want.  What does a filename look like in the directory?

Comment: I take that back, it works! Thanks so much. You're awesome!

Comment: Good job.  You did well for your first time in VBA.